# Is it possible to install paid apps in a development release?

Tags: software-center, 12.10, paid-applications

I wonder if it is somehow possible to install paid applications in a development release of Ubuntu? I think most packages could be easily installed, though is there a way I can convince Ubuntu Software Center to think I am running the older version of Ubuntu so I can install those apps?
Thank you.

Comment: Specific questions about development releases are not constructive, but a general question question might possibly have the potential to be an okay question.